# Where is the user information stored with Janrain?

Tags: facebook, twitter, openid, janrain

I want to use Janrain to let my users sign in with their facebook, twitter etc.

I have read about it on their website but I still don't get the whole picture.

1. Is the actual user information stored in my database or in theirs?
2. What user information should I store in my database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am the technical product manager at Janrain.

The information others have provided is mostly right, but thought I'd chime in for clarity.

1. The Janrain Engage product does not store any of the user profile data we pass through to you. Some of our customers store it and some don't.
2. It depends on your needs. e.g. what profile based changes like experience customization you want to provide.

Some customers who don't want to store the information themselves use our Janrain Capture product to do so. They own and control the data. We just store all of the profile data in the repository we host for them.

Best,

Kevin Ernest Long
Technical Product Manager
Janrain

Answer (score 1):

1. the user information, when provided, is stored in your database.
2. store whatever you wish.  I only care about their name, e-mail and web address if they have one.

Comment: What do you mean the user information when provided? They just sign in with facebook/twitter/google and janrain sends me information about them back to me. So I just choose which fields I want to store in my own database? But if the information is already in janrain, can't I request those fields from their server so I don't have to store anything? Just want to get the picture here.

Comment: yes, you choose what to store in your own database.  janrain, as far as I know, does not store any of that data in their servers.  Presumably they could.  I've seen no indication they do.

Comment: Off topic: When Janrain sends a request to my token_url (eg. mysite.com/sign_in.php) how does the user's web browser go to the log in page? Because the php file that received the request from Janrain is not the same process as the php file that fired up the original page.

Comment: @weng: I don't have that answer.  I have simply been using the Janrain engage Wordpress plugin - I let it take care of these details.